# C# Deserializing a List of custom objects returns null

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class called "ItemToPlace"

```
[Serializable()]
private class ItemToPlace
{
    public ItemToPlace(int ID, float x, float y)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public ItemToPlace()
    {

    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a

```
List<ItemToPlace> items;
```

I serialize the list as follows:

```
Stream stream = File.Open("Data.dat", FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
bformatter.Serialize(stream, items);
stream.Close();
```

Deserializing the list returns null

```
 Stream stream = File.Open("Data.dat", FileMode.Open);
 BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

 // level = null
 level = bformatter.Deserialize(stream) as List<ItemToPlace>;
 stream.Close();
```

I have no clue why this is not working! Any hint would be nice!

Comment: Well instead of using `as`, try casting - then if it's not the right type, you'll find out what it actually was...

Comment: change private class to public class. Serialization only works with public members/classes etc...

Comment: I took your code, pasted it into LINQPad and it worked just fine. Maybe on deserialization you're opening the wrong file?

Comment: casting says "Cannot cast from source type to destination type."
private -> public did not fixed the problem.
the file is the correct one.

i am confused. Maybe it is important that I am using Unity3D? But I don't think so

Comment: What is the type of `level`? `var items = bformatter.Deserialize(stream) as List<ItemToPlace>` works for me.

Comment: I solved the problem - thank you guys! Problem was that ItemToPlace was a nested class. Very sorry for wasting your time...